# i'm trining to run flutter doctor but i'm gettinng this error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

I have started learning flutter, already install android but while running for flutter i'm geeting error what should i do ?

[image]

I have already installed all the required things
[image]

I have also tried to install sdkmanger but i getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to config the flutter path with android SDK
flutter config --android-sdk "path up to SDK"

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

Comment: You have alredy installed Android SDK Command-line Tools (in SDK Manager).

Comment: yes, I have already tried that command but still not working. it displaying like this Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.

Comment: Set android sdk path

Comment: i have already set the path but still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

check the  android_sdk_path\Android\Sdk\cmdline-tools. There may be two or more "latest" folder.. then run flutter doctor -v

Comment: I have 3 folders in that 7.0, latest and latest-2, should I remove 7.0 also with latest-2? . still getting same error as first Image

Comment: Delete "latest-2" folder , and try to run flutter doctor ,,

Comment: i have tried it but still not working